# Why getting second highest list product from this query is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am using adventureworks database. I want to get product from the database whose price is second highest. I am using co-related query for this purpose. I am not quite sure what I might be missing here, in following query.

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice 
FROM SalesLT.Product p1
WHERE 2 =
(
  SELECT COUNT(p2.ProductID) 
  FROM SalesLT.Product p2 
  WHERE p2.ListPrice >= p1.ListPrice
)
```

Comment: Thanks guys for giving following queries, but I was curious about using correlated subquery and wanted to know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c720/1/0) that demonstrates the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ProductID, Name, ListPrice 
FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP(2) ProductID, Name, ListPrice 
  FROM Product 
  ORDER BY ListPrice DESC
) mq
ORDER BY ListPrice
```

In the above example I am getting the top 2 records ordered by price descending.  Then to get the second highest price I take those results and order by ascending and select top 1.

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c720/5/0) example of the following:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice
FROM
(
  SELECT top(2) ProductID, Name, ListPrice,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ListPrice DESC) rowNum
  FROM Product
) twoEntries 
WHERE rowNum = 2
```

Comment: *@Mokchhya*, I helped you out a little by formatting your query and provided a SQL Fiddle sample.  Hope you don't mind.